# Add hyperlink efficiently to text just replaced on Google Slides

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-slides, google-slides-api

I am inserting a list of instagram handles from Google Sheets to Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

- The Google Sheets contains a list of instagram handles, such as @Apple, @Google, etc. For convenience, in the recreation below, let's assume that the handle "@Apple" has already been retrieved from the sheet as a string and placed into a variable called `handle`.
- The Google slide contains a single placeholder in a textbox, {{handle}}.

My goal is to insert "@Apple" into the placeholder {{handle}}, and add a hyperlink (https://www.instagram.com/apple/) to it. I.e., I want to add a hyperlink to the text I just inserted/replaced.

I am able to achieve this with the code below, but it is extremely inefficient. In my actual application, there are a lot of entries to insert, and many more shapes on the slides, so I would love to be able to do this efficiently. I am open to trying other methods too. Any guidance is appreciated.

My code:

```
var handle = "@Apple";

// extract username to get url
let regExp = new RegExp("[^@]*$");
var username = regExp.exec(handle)[0];
var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username;

// insert the handle at {{handle}} and make it a hyperlink
var allShapes = (currentSlide.getShapes());
allShapes.forEach(function(shape) {
    var text = shape.getText();
    var n = text.replaceAllText("{{handle}}", handle);
    if (n > 0) {
        var textRange = text.getTextStyle();
        text.find(handle).forEach((v) => {
            v.getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(url);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that the community can use to see what you'd like to do? Like a dummy sheet so we can visualize and replicate what you have. You may include your desired output in it as well.

Comment: @Saddles Thank you for your comment! I have read through the page you linked and edited my question. Is it clearer now? P.S. I am a little confused by what you mean by "dummy sheet". Should I create a new Google sheet, or should I make a table here in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In your situation, how about using Slides API? When Slides API is used, your script can be modified as follows. I guessed that when Slides API is used, the process cost can be reduced.

In this modification, from `The Google Sheets contains a list of instagram handles, such as @Apple, @Google, etc.`, it supposes that several replace texts are used. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slide. And, [please enable Slides API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

First, please set `handles` for your actual situation. In this modification, you can use multiple replacement texts. In this sample, the
shapes with the text `{{handle}}` are replaced with `@Apple`. The
shapes with the text `{{handle2}}` are replaced with `@Google`. And, the hyperlinks are set.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Prepare values.
  var handles = [ // Please prepare this object for your actual situation.
    { replaceFrom: "{{handle}}", replaceTo: "@Apple" },
    { replaceFrom: "{{handle2}}", replaceTo: "@Google" },
  ];
  handles.forEach(e => {
    let regExp = new RegExp("[^@]*$");
    var username = regExp.exec(e.replaceTo)[0];
    var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username;
    e.url = url;
  });

  // Replace texts and set hyperlinks.
  var s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var sId = s.getId();
  var currentSlide = s.getSelection().getCurrentPage();
  var pageId = currentSlide.getObjectId();
  var obj = Slides.Presentations.Pages.get(sId, pageId);
  var requests = handles.map(({ replaceFrom, replaceTo, url }) => {
    var temp = [{ replaceAllText: { containsText: { text: replaceFrom }, replaceText: replaceTo, pageObjectIds: [pageId] } }];
    obj.pageElements.forEach(e => e.shape.text.textElements.forEach(f => {
      var t = f?.textRun?.content;
      if (t && t.trim() == replaceFrom) {
        temp.push({ updateTextStyle: { style: { link: { url } }, objectId: e.objectId, fields: "link" } });
      }
    }));
    return temp;
  });
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ requests }, sId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the selected page of Google Slide is processed with `handles` by one API call.

#### Note:

- As an important point, from your showing script, the URL is created using your script. Please be careful about this.
- From your script, only the shapes are searched. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)
- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> but my situation is as follows: For the list of handles on my Google sheet (in a single column), for each row, I will 1. create a new slide from a template, with {{handle}} written inside, 2. replace {{handle}} the handle (e.g. @Apple), 3. insert the url. So instead of updating multiple locations on a single slide, I'm actually creating a slide every time I read a new row. Is it still possible to use batchUpdate in this situation?

Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the column number from `in a single column`. So, in this sample script, it supposes that it's column "A" with the header row. And also, unfortunately, I couldn't understand `create a new slide from a template`. So, in this sample script, it is supposed that the 1st-page slide in a Google Slide is a template slide. And, the 1st template slide is copied. When these are reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, please copy and paste the script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please set `templateSlideId` and `sheetName`. **It supposes that Google Slide of `templateSlideId` has a template slide on the 1st page. Please be careful about this.**

This script uses Slides API. Please be careful about this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set your template Google Slide ID.
  // In this script, the 1st slide is used by copying.
  var templateSlideId = "###";
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  // Prepare values.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a);
  var handles = values.map(([a]) => ({ replaceFrom: "{{handle}}", replaceTo: a }))
  handles.forEach(e => {
    let regExp = new RegExp("[^@]*$");
    var username = regExp.exec(e.replaceTo)[0];
    var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username;
    e.url = url;
  });

  // Duplicate a template slide and replace texts and set hyperlinks.
  var topPageId = SlidesApp.openById(templateSlideId).getSlides()[0].getObjectId();
  var requests1 = [...Array(handles.length)].map((_, i) => ({ duplicateObject: { objectId: topPageId } }));
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ requests: requests1 }, templateSlideId);
  var [, ...obj] = Slides.Presentations.get(templateSlideId).slides;
  var requests = handles.map(({ replaceFrom, replaceTo, url }, i) => {
    var temp = [{ replaceAllText: { containsText: { text: replaceFrom }, replaceText: replaceTo, pageObjectIds: [obj[i].objectId] } }];
    obj[i].pageElements.forEach(e => e.shape.text.textElements.forEach(f => {
      var t = f?.textRun?.content;
      if (t && t.trim() == replaceFrom) {
        temp.push({ updateTextStyle: { style: { link: { url } }, objectId: e.objectId, fields: "link" } });
      }
    }));
    return temp;
  });
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ requests }, templateSlideId);
}
```

When this script is run, the 1st page (template slide) of the Google Slide is copied. And, the text `{{handle}}` is replaced using each row of cells "A2:A" and set the hyperlinks.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I apologise for not having further clarified this in my initial question, but my situation is as follows: For the list of handles on my Google sheet (in a single column), for each row, I will 1. create a new slide from a template, with {{handle}} written inside, 2. replace {{handle}} the handle (e.g. @Apple), 3. insert the url. So instead of updating multiple locations on a single slide, I'm actually creating a slide every time I read a new row. Is it still possible to use batchUpdate in this situation?

Comment: @steak Thank you for replying. First, I apologize that I couldn't understand your actual expected result from your posted question because of my poor English skill. From your reply, by guessing your actual expected result, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result again, I apologize agian.

Answer (score 0):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

You may also use this code to achieve what you'd like to do:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  const handles = ["@Apple", "@Google", "@Microsoft"];
  const slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();

  slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
    const handle = handles[i];
    const shapes = slide.getShapes();

    shapes.forEach((shape) => {
      const text = shape.getText();
      const n = text.replaceAllText("{{handle}}", handle);

      if (n > 0) {
        const regExp = new RegExp("[^@]*$");
        const username = regExp.exec(handle)[0];
        const url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username;
        text.find(handle).forEach((v) => {
          v.getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(url);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

You're already getting what you'd like, this was just made to loop through all the slides and replace all of `{{handle}}` with what you'll put in the array `handles`.

#### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT]

#### REFERENCE

- [Class Slide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide)

### UPDATE

Since you'll be using a spreadsheet, you may change this:

```
const handles = ["@Apple", "@Google", "@Microsoft"];
```

To:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const handles = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
```

> *Note: Like with @[Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653)'s updated answer, I'm also assuming that your Instagram handles are on `A2:A`.*

The full code would become:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const handles = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  const slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();

  slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
    const handle = handles[i];
    const shapes = slide.getShapes();

    shapes.forEach((shape) => {
      const text = shape.getText();
      const n = text.replaceAllText("{{handle}}", handle);

      if (n > 0) {
        const regExp = new RegExp("[^@]*$");
        const username = regExp.exec(handle)[0];
        const url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username;
        text.find(handle).forEach((v) => {
          v.getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(url);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Feel free to clarify if I've misunderstood what your goal is. I'll be happy to help in any way I can!